# How to input time range in robot framework, for testing popup window

Tags: robotframework

Hi I have pop up window where I need to input time/date range and then check the results on the graph. What is the best way to do that in robot framework using standard libraries?Im asking how to input date in the best and tidy way in to the code.

Answer (score 0):

This just isn't a great question.  Have you looked through the robot framework documentation much?  Have you even googled it?  I find it hard to believe you wouldn't come across the DateTime library.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html